# Confusing ActiveModelSerializer behavior. What is going on and why isn't it serializing correctly?

Tags: active-model-serializers

My serializer is simply accessing a key in the ActiveModel object and inside the serializer, it seems to return the nested hash. this is my serializer:

```
module Api
  module V20150315
    class RecipeToolSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      cached
      delegate :cache_key, to: :object

      attributes :id,
                 :display_name,
                 :images,
                 :display_price,
                 :description,
                 :main_imagez,
                 :subtitle

      def display_name
        object.display_name
      end

      def images
        object.story.get_spree_product.master.images
      end

      def display_price
        object.story.get_spree_product.master.display_price
      end

      def description
        object.story.description
      end

      def main_imagez
        binding.pry
        object.story.main_image
      end

      def subtitle
        object.story.get_spree_product.subtitle
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The method in question is the main_imagez method. When I hit that pry, object.story.main_image returns:

```
pry(#<Api::V20150315::RecipeToolSerializer>)> object.story.main_image
{
                  :key => "/spec/support/uploads/story/main_image/1/20160321-1706-2988-3566/someimage",
           :bucket_url => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/test_bucket",
               :policy => "somethingsomething",
            :signature => "someencryptedcode",
                  :acl => "public-read",
    :aws_access_key_id => "somekey",
          :process_url => nil
}
```

But inside my test when I inspect the response... strangeness occurs:

Here's my test:

```
it "should have a main image attribute for each recipe tool" do
        response = JSON.parse(subject.body)
        binding.pry
        response['recipe_tools'].each do |recipe_tool_response|
          binding.pry
          expect(recipe_tool_response["main_image"]).to match /(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png)/
        end
      end
```

and the binding:

```
[3] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApiRecipesRecipeToolsController::GETIndex::WhenGivenRecipeParams>)> JSON.parse(subject.body)
{
    "recipe_tools" => [
        [0] {
                       "id" => 1,
             "display_name" => "Testing Tool",
                   ...
              "main_imagez" => {
                "main_image" => {
                       "url" => "//d2v868ucs1c5n9.cloudfront.net/spec/support/uploads/story/main_image/1/20160321-1706-2988-3566/blueapronimage.jpg",
                    "medium" => {
                        "url" => "//someurl/spec/support/uploads/story/main_image/1/20160321-1706-2988-3566/some_image.jpg"
                    },
                     "thumb" => {
                        "url" => "//someurl/spec/support/uploads/story/main_image/1/20160321-1706-2988-3566/some_image_thumb.jpg"
                    }
                }
            },
                 "subtitle" => ""
        },
```

Any idea why main_imagez loses its structure and becomes this weird nested hash like thing?

I think this is the most important part:

I have a method called to_hash inside the main_image method's carrierwave uploader:

```
def to_hash
    {
      key: key,
      bucket_url: bucket_url,
      policy: policy,
      signature: signature,
      acl: acl,
      aws_access_key_id: aws_access_key_id,
      process_url: process_url
    }
  end
```

Basically, I think a method is called after the serializer's methods (including to_hash) are applied that changes the main_image object which looks like a hash but isn't really a hash...main_image actually returns a main_image_uploader object. In order to convert that to a hash, I bet the to_hash method is applied but unfortunately we monkey-patched that method. How do I find out what's called and whether monkey-patching to_hash was dangerous?